# Finding elements of an array with an array of indexes (Ruby)

Tags: ruby, arrays, indexing

Using `array.each_with_index` returned an array containing the indexes of several elements which I set equal to a variable, `indexes`. I just want to know how I can then find the elements at each of those indexes like `array[indexes] #=> element 1, element 2, etc`. I tried the previous example with no luck, and also `array[indexes.each {|x| x}]`.

Not sure why this is so hard, but I am brand new to coding and I couldn't find the answer elsewhere.

Comment: Give the code you have tried.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is what [Array#values_at](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Array.html#method-i-values_at) is for:

```
indices = [0,2] 
p ["a", "b", "c", "a"].values_at(*indices) # => ["a", "c"]
```

Comment: This actually is what I was looking for, and I allows me to do what I need. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are probably starting wrong.

each_with_index is meant to iterate over your array with an index like this:

```
array.each_with_index do |element, index|

 #do stuff with the element and the index here

end
```

If you already have your array of indexes and you really want to do it that way you can:

```
indexes.each do |index|

 array[index]

end
```

You should think of `each` as a for loop other the element, passing consecutivly each element to the variable in `| |`. Inside the `{ }` or `do ... end` you can then do things with your element. It's not meant to be used like x = array.each :)

Comment: When I said I used `array.each_with_index` I just left off the rest of the the block I used to find which indexes I wanted. Should have left that to be clear. Your solution works, thank you greatly!